# RxJs: delay onNext for some values with?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there a way to delay onNext for certain values?, eg:

```
let subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({value: 100})
subject.onNext({ value: 123})
subject.onNext({ value: 999})
subject.onNext({ value: 120})  // could this be delayed with 500ms before being delivered to subscribers?
```

Possible options:

- Use different subjects one with delay, other without (but I would like to avoid that)
- use delayWithSelector (it's not included in rx.lite.js, so not an option)
- do it via setTimeout(() => subject.onNext({value:123}), 500) (does not look Reactive)

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to just flatMap observables and emit delayed ones.

Like so:

```
const {Observable} = Rx;

const source = Observable.interval(500)
  .flatMap((e) => {
    if (e % 2 === 0) {
      return Observable.of(e)
        .delay(2000);
    }
    else {
      return Observable.of(e); 
    }
  });

source
  .subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

This will give you results like such:

```
"1, 3, 0, 5, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6"
```

Easier to understand:

```
- = 250ms
-------- = 2000ms

interval(500)
0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-(10)

.flatMap(...)
--------0---2---4---6
--1---3---5---7---9--

source (interval().flatMap())
--1---3-0-5-2-7-4-9-6
```

Comment: and how do i use flatMap with Subjects in this way? There is no "interval" or initial values, that i need

Comment: Subjects are Observables. You can apply the same operators to them as the Observable created by the interval.